# How look for a string in a JSON file and then getting the next one in the list?

Tags: python, arrays, json, search

I think it's pretty simple what I want to do, but I'm struggling a little bit because of fundamentals I don't have.

What I want to do is look for a certain string on a JSON file and then, after I find it, take the next string on list instead of the one I found.

The code I'm using right now is this:

```
jsonarquivos = open(nomejson, 'r')
data = json.load(jsonarquivos)
for sub_dict in data:
   if imageid in data:
```

Now I don't know what to put on the `if`.

**EDIT**

There is a little example of how the JSON looks like:

```
["lccw2w", "lcdrqx", "lck63p", "lck9d3"]
```

so If I'm looking for the imageid = "lcdrqx", I want "lck63p" to come out instead.

Comment: Please add a short sample the JSON input data to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list.index() to determine its index in the list, then access the next item in the list:

```
with open(nomejson, 'r') as jsonarquivos:
    data = json.load(jsonarquivos)
    for sub_dict in data:
        if imageid in data:
            i = data.index(imageid)
            if i + 1 < len(data):
                print(f'next image is {data[i+1]}')
            else:
                print(f'{imageid} is the last item')
```